# Lambda function works in Lambda console but not in Test Simulator (Beta)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an issue where my lambda function is working when I run a test in the Lambda console but not when I run that same code in the Test Simulator (Beta). The following is what I'm putting into both places, with redactions for sensitive information:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"session": {
    "new": false,
    "sessionId": "xxxxx",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "xxxxx"
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": "xxxxx"
    }
},
"context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
        "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "Display": {
        "token": ""
    },
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "xxxxx"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "xxxxx"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "xxxxx",
            "supportedInterfaces": {
                "AudioPlayer": {},
                "Display": {
                    "templateVersion": "1.0",
                    "markupVersion": "1.0"
                }
            }
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "xxxxx"
    }
},
"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "xxxxx",
    "timestamp": "2018-02-13T05:22:11Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "intent": {
        "name": "OpenTicketIntent",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "Project": {
                "name": "Project",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            },
            "Assignee": {
                "name": "Assignee",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            },
            "TicketType": {
                "name": "TicketType",
                "value": "bug",
                "resolutions": {
                    "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                        {
                            "authority": "xxxxx",
                            "status": {
                                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": {
                                        "name": "Bug",
                                        "id": "xxxxx"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            },
            "IssueTitle": {
                "name": "IssueTitle",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            }
        }
    },
    "dialogState": "STARTED"
}
```

}

When I ask my skill to open itself in the simulator it opens perfectly. I get the correct response. But when I ask it a question afterwards ("Open a bug", and many variations that I have in my dialog model) I'm getting "There was a problem with the requested skill's response". Am I doing something wrong? Will this not work unless I'm using a physical device?

Comment: The JSON you provided is an Alexa Request, not an Alexa Response. If you are sending that back, she won't understand. Can you post the code you are using to send the response?

Answer (score 1):

regarding any issues with your lambda function, you should check the log files of your lambda function.

1. Select your lambda function in the Lambda Management Console
2. Click "Monitoring" (besides the tab "Configuration")
3. On the right side, you can see the box "Invocation Errors". Inside the box, click "Jump to logs"

You will then be redirected to the latest log file of your lambda function. I think you either will be able to solve the issue on your own or provide additional infos on the error to us.

Cheers, Magnus

Comment: I'm getting zero errors in the Cloudwatch logs for the lambda function. Everything seems to be going smoothly there. Interestingly enough, when I invoke the intent from the Echo device I get "Sorry, I'm having trouble accessing your xxx skill right now". This doesn't happen when opening the skill for the first time, just when invoking this intent. It's the only intent I have as well.